# Xamarin.forms - Xam.Plugin.Media throwing error This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget-package

I am using Xam.Plugin.Media for implementing functions for taking and picking a photo on Android and iOS. I installed the latest stable version of Xam.Plugin.Media NuGet package (version 4.0.0.9) and followed the steps from Author on GitHub and when I press the button this message pops up and no matter what I do it wont go away. So if you any of you had this problem and resloved it please help me, and if you have any additional information about this error, please, help me.

[image]

I have tried the following to resolve this, but with no success:

- Re-installing package several times
- Deleting Obj and Bin folders
- Clean + build

This is my view model:

```
public ICommand UploadImageCommand => new Command(async () =>
    {
        await Resiliency.TryAsync(IsBusy, async () =>
        {
            await UploadImageAsync();
        });

    });

    private async Task UploadImageAsync()
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            await DialogService.ShowExceptionAlertAsync("No Camera");
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            SaveToAlbum = true
        });

        if (file == null)
            return;

        _imagePath = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = file.GetStream();
            return stream;
        });
    }
```

Additional information:

- When debbuging it crashes on the first line of the method - "await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();"
- This is happening on Android and I am using physical device (Huawei P9 Lite 7.0 API 24), but the same happens on Emulator API 23 6.0
- I am using Visual studio 2015 enterprise with update 3
- Yes the package is installed on the core project and on the android and iOS project

Comment: Install the package in not just your PCL/.NetStd library project, but also the iOS and Android application projects.

Comment: Yes I have done that, all three projects are checked when installing package

Comment: Double check that ios and android platforms have the nuget package installed. Also what is DialogService? is that implemented on both platforms as well? make sure you add this to the mainapplication.cs CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);

Comment: ["This plugin uses the Current Activity Plugin:"](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#android-current-activity-setup) CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the response of the original Developer on the GitHub Repository

[Xam.Plugin.Media throwing error This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly #559](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/559)

You can also download the sample and see how it works

Comment: This doesn't work, I have the same problem and it seems to be a common one.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin did you try the sample app? it's not a common issue since not many have replied to that thread and it certainly worked for me on version 3.1.3. Please try the sample app and share your details with the GitHub thread if you have any.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using version 4 of the plugin and that is what is giving me a problem. I will download the sample from Github and let you know...btw do you have a link for version 3.1.3 by any chance?

Comment: It's a nuget package. So, you can download and install any version you want from visual studio IDE. You can also download it from the nuget website, but then you will need to install it manually and it's much easier to do in visual studio. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media/

Comment: I have installed xam.plugin.media version 4.0.1.1 and followed the github installation instructions and I get the error:

***System.NotImplementedException: This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.***

I have tried numerous things to find out where the error comes from including rebuilding, re-installing etc, but it will not work. I have tried it using API 24,25,26 and the same thing occurs.

Comment: I managed to get it working, I'm not sure how. Having created several new projects, this one worked.